# Why doesn't spring method injection work in Kotlin?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, cglib

I try to implement method injection using Spring 5.1.6 and Kotlin 1.3.20

When i implement method injection using Kotlin method getNotification isn't return new object of SchoolNotification. I get Kotlin NPE.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
open class SchoolNotification {
override fun toString(): String {
    return Objects.toString(this)
    }
}
```

StudentServices:

```
@Component
open class StudentServices {
@Lookup
fun getNotification(): SchoolNotification {
    return null!!
    }
 }
```

Everything is ok when i write the same code with Java

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SchoolNotification {

}
```

StudentServices:

```
@Component
public class StudentServices {

@Lookup
public SchoolNotification getNotification() {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Main

```
fun main() {
  val ctx = AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ReplacingLookupConfig::class.java)
  val bean = ctx.getBean(StudentServices::class.java)
  println(bean.getNotification())
  println(bean.getNotification())
  ctx.close()
}
```

What am i doing wrong using Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to making your class `open`, you need to make your method `open` too, otherwise the method is still marked as `final` and Spring won't be able to provide its own implementation for it in a subclass:

```
@Lookup
open fun getNotification(): SchoolNotification {
    return null!!
}
```